# Is this is possible - one model many fields with formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm building some forms, and I want to use formtastic for it.

I have a Question Model (id, subject_id, question) and a Question
has_many :answers (id, question_id, answer).
So subject can have many questions (and I used nested forms for it), but now I
want to build form with answer fields, if there will be 1, 2...n
questions, than I have to create 1, 2... n answer fields.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to build formtastic for many answers
(each answer will have hidden field with question_id).

A form should look like

```
start_form
Question 1
answer 1 (as textarea)
question_id_1 (as hidden)

Question 2
answer 2 (as textarea)
question_id_2 (as hidden)

Question n
answer n (as textarea)
question_id_n (as hidden)

submit
```

Answer (score 2):

Watch the [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) Railscast, then watch the [Formtastic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1) series. Those screencasts will answer your questions better than most of us could.